# Display the count of nested objects in ElasticSearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, select, count, nested, size

I'd like to get all the docs that meet my search criteria and sort them based on the number of nested object in a particular field. I'd like to display the count number as well. I have got the former working, but having hard time figuring out how to do the latter.

Here's my query:

```
GET _search
{
  "_source": "nested_objects",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"nested" : {
            "path" : "nested_objects",
            "query" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "should" :[
                      {"term" : {"nested_objects.is_active": true}}
                    ]
                }
            },
            "score_mode": "sum"
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This shows the result as:

```
"_source": {
  "nested_objects": [
    {
      "is_active": true
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

However, I need the output to be like this:

```
"_source": {
  "size": 4,
  "nested_objects": [
    {
      "is_active": true
    },
    {
      "is_active": true
    }, 
    {
      "is_active": true
    },
    {
      "is_active": true
    } 
   ]
 }
```

Any idea how I can get the size displayed in the query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all I needed was to add `"inner_hits": {}` under my nested query:

```
GET _search
{
  "_source": "innert_hits",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"nested" : {
            "path" : "nested_objects",
            "query" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "should" :[
                      {"term" : {"nested_objects.is_active": true}}
                    ]
                }
            },
            "inner_hits": {},
            "score_mode": "sum"
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It doesn't return the result as I wanted in my above requirements, but it's good enough for my use case.